# Question related to Single-precision floating-point format

Tags: binary

- What number does the following word stand for?

  > $$\color{red}{1}\;\;\;\;\color{blue}{10000101}\;\;\;\;11110010011110100000000$$

Where the red one is the sign (it's called the sign bit which determines the sign of the number), the blue binary number is the Exponent, and the other bits are significand precision.

Based on [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) I tried to use the following formula:

> $$\text{Value}=\left(-1\right)^{\operatorname{sign}}\cdot2^{\left(e-127\right)}\cdot\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{23}b_{23-i}\ \cdot2^{-i}\right)$$

$$\text{Value}=$$$$\left(-1\right)^{\color{red}{1}}\cdot2^{\left(\color{blue}{133}-127\right)}\cdot\left(1+2^{-1}+2^{-2}+2^{-3}+2^{-4}+2^{-7}+2^{-10}+2^{-11}+2^{-12}+2^{-13}+2^{-15}\right)$$$$=-124.619140625$$

is that right?

Comment: In IEEE floats, the first black $1$ should rather be blue ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, the colors I've used were arbitrary and I used them to mention which number I'm referring to

Comment: Odd that you have 24 bits of "fraction", rather than your link's 23.

Comment: @user715522:  Hagen's point is that the leading $1$ in your mantissa should be part of the exponent.  Then you have $8$ exponent bits like you expect.  You also have $23$ mantissa bits, which is correct.  A nit:  it is a sign bit, not sign bits, as there is only one of them.

Comment: @RossMillikan, yu are right,I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scripture:
$$\color{red}{1}\;\;\;\;\color{blue}{10000101}\;\;\;\;11110010011110100000000$$
there are three different parts. In particular, the exponent is a natural number, so you hav to convert it from binary. The general rule to do this is:
$$S=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}2^i\cdot B_i$$
where $i=0$ means that you have to start from the right side of the binary number and $B_i$ is the $i-$term of the sequence of lenght $N$.

> With this clarification, your formula becomes:
>   $$V=\left(-1\right)^{\operatorname{sign}}\cdot2^{\left(\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}2^i\cdot B_i-127\right)}\cdot\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^{23}B_{23-i}\ \cdot2^{-i}\right)$$

Comment: I tried to use the formula and I edited my error, can you please check that?

Comment: @haha, I did that, thanks for the answer.

Comment: at least check y answer, then I will accept your answer

Comment: @user715522: your answer is correct: I've checkes it with IEEE 754 converter tool.